# XSS vulnerability in Rails (merged params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss

I recently discovered (thanks to a bug bounty user) that my site has XSS vulnerabilities. After some playing around, I discovered the cause is in our locale switch in the navbar, such as:

```
<%= link_to "日本語",  params.merge(locale: "ja", only_path: true), target:"_self", onClick:"ga('send','event','Navbar','Link Clicked','Language setting ja');" %>
```

This allows malicious code to be freely injected but I cannot for the life of me work out how to fix it without either breaking the locale switch or the creation of alternative issues.

I have checked other XSS related posts on here but I think the issue is a little bit above my ability to even comprehend, let alone fix right now. If anyone has any advice on how to prevent this XSS problem, I will be extremely grateful as it has become quite stressful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being ridiculously simple so I will post here just in case anyone else ever searches for a similar problem.

As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization I started by adding this to the `application_controller.rb` file:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

With that, I could simply delete most of the original (vulnerable) locale switch and now have:

```
<li><%= link_to "日本語", locale: "ja" %></li>
```

Vulnerability removed yet functionality retained. Really was that simple. Dealing with legacy code can be a pain at times, thankfully this wasn't  anywhere near as complicated as I initially assumed.